# Set 'option' attribute of CheckboxGroup via Apex

Tags: apex, javascript-controller, attribute

So this is an example of what i need to know.

Basically i want to set the `option` attribute of my `lightning:checkboxGroup` via apex

I even tried with a Map instead of an Object in apex controller.

**example.cmp**

```
<aura:component controller="exampleController" implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes">

    <aura:attribute name="options" type="List" />

    <aura:handler name="init" value="{! this }" action="{! c.init }"/>
    <aura:if isTrue="{! !empty(v.options)}">
        <lightning:checkboxGroup name="Product" 
                                 label="label" 
                                 options="{! v.options}" />
    </aura:if>

</aura:aura:component>
```

**exampleControlle.js**

```
({
    init : function(cmp, event, helper){
        var action = cmp.get('c.doInit');
        action.setCallback(this, function(response){
            if(response.getState() == 'SUCCESS'){                    
                cmp.set('v.options', response.getReturnValue(););
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
})
```

**exampleController.apxc**

```
public class exampleController{

    private class ProductOption{
        @AuraEnabled private String label {get; set;} 
        @AuraEnabled private String value {get; set;} 
    }

    @AuraEnabled
    public static list<ProductOption> doInit(){
        list<ProductOption> res = new list<ProductOption>();

        ProductOption tempProductOption = new ProductOption();

        tempProductOption.label = 'egLabel';
        tempProductOption.value = 'egValue';

        res.add(tempProductOption);

        return res;
    }
}
```

Then i get this error message

[image]

Thanks for help.

Comment: Set the default value to either empty list or any other default value(s) and you are done **<aura:attribute name="options" type="List" default="[]" />** and you don't need to add the empty check using *aura:if*. and also make sure the add the required attributes and the syntax as highlighted by others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are missing here is having a required `value` property for [`lightning:checkboxGroup`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:checkboxGroup/specification).

To solve the issue, add attribute to hold `value` attribute, an example here:

---

component:

```
<aura:component controller="exampleController" implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes">

    <aura:attribute name="options" type="List"/>
    <aura:attribute name="value" type="List"/>
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{! this }" action="{! c.init }"/>

    <lightning:checkboxGroup name="Product" 
        label="label" 
        value="{!v.value}"
        options="{!v.options}" />
</aura:component>
```

---

server side controller:

```
({
    init : function(cmp, event, helper){
        var action = cmp.get('c.doInit');
        action.setCallback(this, function(response){
            if(response.getState() == 'SUCCESS'){        
                cmp.set('v.options', response.getReturnValue());  
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
})
```

---

Best way to resolve issue is look closely at documentation, as lightning components sometimes does not give a descriptive error message. Always check require attributes first before proceeding to debugging.

Comment: This answer won't solve the error, unfortunately. The problem here is the options attribute is required, and if is null, results in this error. I ended up using an aura:if rendering solution to prevent this error from happening, but specifying a default value would work, too.

Comment: Initially I used an `aura:if` and also default value as per David's recommendation, after removing all extra stuff, this worked fine in my DEV org. Also I have debug mode on and disabled cache.

Answer (score 2):

```
cmp.set('options', response.getReturnValue());
```

You're missing a `v.` to set the attribute value:

```
cmp.set('v.options', response.getReturnValue()); // removed extra semicolon; nice catch, Raul.
```

so the attribute's never getting populated.

You'll probably also want to add a `default` value to your `options` attribute, since the values are being loaded asynchronously; e.g.

```
<aura:attribute name="options" type="List" default="[{'label': '--none--', value:''}]" />
```

Comment: Thanks a lot David for the answer, but i just missed in the example, unfortunately this is not the real problem

Comment: While I do not have this set up in a dev org, I think the issue is still that `v.options` is undefined/null, because you are loading it asynchronously. See sfdcfox's comment on Raul's answer.

Comment: i tried to check the attribute first, using `aura:if` but i still get the same error, i also added `<aura.attribute name"vale" type="String" />` for the value attribute of ` lightning:checkboxGroup `...